# Employee and EmployeeDemo, how to get the following output for two separate employees?

Tags: java, class, methods

I have to create an Employee Class and a Demo class that uses it. I have the following:

**Employee Class:**

```
public class KNW_Employee
{
  private int empID;
  private double payRate;
  private double weeklyHrs;

  public KNW_Employee()
  {
    this.empID = empID;
    this.payRate = payRate;
    this.weeklyHrs = weeklyHrs;
  }

  public KNW_Employee(int empID)
  {
    this.empID = empID;
  }

  public KNW_Employee(int empID, double payRate, double weeklyHrs)
  {
    this.empID = empID;
    this.payRate = payRate;
    this.weeklyHrs = weeklyHrs;
  }

  public void setID(int empID)
  {
    this.empID = empID;
  }

  public void setPayRate(double payRate)
  {
    this.payRate = payRate;
  }

  public void setWeeklyHrs(double weeklyHrs)
  {
    this.weeklyHrs = weeklyHrs;
  }

  public int getID()
  {
    return empID;
  }

  public double getPayRate()
  {
    return payRate;
  }

  public double getWeeklyHrs()
  {
    return weeklyHrs;
  }

  public double getWeeklyPay()
  {
    return weeklyHrs * payRate;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return "ID for First Employee: " + getID() +
      "\nPayRate for First Employee: " + getPayRate() +
      "\nWeekly Hours for First Employee: " + getWeeklyHrs() +
      "\nWeekly Pay for First Employee:  " + getWeeklyPay() +
      "\n\nID for Second Employee: " + getID() +
      "\nPayRate for Second Employee: " + getPayRate() +
      "\nWeekly Hours for Second Employee: " + getWeeklyHrs() +
      "\nWeekly Pay for Second Employee:  " + getWeeklyPay();
  }
}
```

**Employee Demo:**

```
class EmployeeDemo
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    //Create scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Declare variables
    int emp1;
    int emp2;
    double hour1;
    double hour2;
    double pay1;
    double pay2;

    //Ask for employee's ID
    System.out.println("Enter ID for Employee 1: ");
    emp1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter ID for Employee 2: ");
    emp2 = input.nextInt();

    //Ask for employee's hours
    System.out.println("Enter Employee 1's Hours: ");
    hour1 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter Employee 2's Hours: ");
    hour2 = input.nextDouble();

    //Ask for employee's pay
    System.out.println("Enter Employee 1's Pay: ");
    pay1 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter Employee 2's Pay: ");
    pay2 = input.nextDouble();

    //Call Employee Class
    KNW_Employee e = new KNW_Employee();
    e.getID();
    e.getWeeklyHrs();
    e.getPayRate();

    System.out.println(e.toString());
  }
}
```

I just need to print the `toString()` for 2 separate employees. It lets me type in the data, but once it comes to print out the data, I just keep getting zeros. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not `set` the values to the `employee` objects, which needs to be done as shown in the below code with inline comments:

```
    //create employee objects first
    KNW_Employee emploee1 = new KNW_Employee();
    KNW_Employee emploee2 = new KNW_Employee();


    //Ask for employee's ID
    System.out.println("Enter ID for Employee 1: ");
    emp1 = input.nextInt();
    emploee1.setID(emp1);//set the id value for employee1
    System.out.println("Enter ID for Employee 2: ");
    emp2 = input.nextInt();
    emploee2.setID(emp2);//set the id value for employee2

    //Ask for employee's hours
     System.out.println("Enter Employee 1's Hours: ");
     hour1 = input.nextDouble();
     emploee1.setWeeklyHrs(hour1);
     System.out.println("Enter Employee 2's Hours: ");
     hour2 = input.nextDouble();
     emploee1.setWeeklyHrs(hour2);

     //Ask for employee's pay
     System.out.println("Enter Employee 1's Pay: ");
     pay1 = input.nextDouble();
      emploee1.setPayRate(pay1);
     System.out.println("Enter Employee 2's Pay: ");
     pay2 = input.nextDouble();
     emploee1.setPayRate(pay2);
    
   System.out.println(emploee1);//print employee1 (this calls toString())
   System.out.println(emploee2);//print employee2 (this calls toString())
```

---

The other important point is that you don't need to call `toString()` method on the `employee` object explicitly, rather when you use `System.out.println(emploee1)`, it invokes `toString()` implicitly, you can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html) on this (text copied below, emphasis mine).

> The Object's toString() method returns a String representation of the
> object, which is very useful for debugging. The String representation
> for an object depends entirely on the object, which is why you need to
> override toString() in your classes. You can use **toString() along with > System.out.println() to display a text representation of an object**, > such as an instance of Book:
>
> **System.out.println(firstBook.toString())**;

Answer (score 0):

```
NW_Employee e1 = new KNW_Employee();
e1.setID(emp1);
//set other properties

NW_Employee e2 = new KNW_Employee();
e2.setID(emp2);
//set other properties

//output 
System.out.println(e1);
System.out.println(e2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your instance creation and value setting to KNW_Employee in EmployeeDemo. Replace your  //Call Employee Class code with following code.

```
KNW_Employee employee1 = new KNW_Employee(emp1,pay1,hour1);
KNW_Employee employee2 = new KNW_Employee(emp2,pay2,hour2);

System.out.println(employee1.toString());
System.out.println(employee2.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package org.sunil.addressbook.dao;

public class KNW_Employee
{
  private int empID;
  private String empNumber;
  private double payRate;
  private double weeklyHrs;

  public KNW_Employee(int empID,String empNumber,double payRate,double weeklyHrs)
  {
    this.empID = empID;
    this.payRate = payRate;
    this.weeklyHrs = weeklyHrs;
    this.empNumber=empNumber;
  }

  public int getEmpID() {
    return empID;
}

public void setEmpID(int empID) {
    this.empID = empID;
}

public String getEmpNumber() {
    return empNumber;
}

public void setEmpNumber(String empNumber) {
    this.empNumber = empNumber;
}

public KNW_Employee(int empID)
  {
    this.empID = empID;
  }

  public KNW_Employee(int empID, double payRate, double weeklyHrs)
  {
    this.empID = empID;
    this.payRate = payRate;
    this.weeklyHrs = weeklyHrs;
  }

  public void setID(int empID)
  {
    this.empID = empID;
  }

  public void setPayRate(double payRate)
  {
    this.payRate = payRate;
  }

  public void setWeeklyHrs(double weeklyHrs)
  {
    this.weeklyHrs = weeklyHrs;
  }

  public int getID()
  {
    return empID;
  }

  public double getPayRate()
  {
    return payRate;
  }

  public double getWeeklyHrs()
  {
    return weeklyHrs;
  }

  public double getWeeklyPay()
  {
    return weeklyHrs * payRate;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return "ID for "+getEmpNumber()+" Employee: " + getID() +
      "\nPayRate for "+getEmpNumber()+" Employee: " + getPayRate() +
      "\nWeekly Hours for "+getEmpNumber()+" Employee: " + getWeeklyHrs() +
      "\nWeekly Pay for "+getEmpNumber()+" Employee:  " + getWeeklyPay();
  }
}
```

And the Demo Class should be of the following manner:-

```
package org.sunil.addressbook.dao;

import java.util.Scanner;

class EmployeeDemo
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    //Create scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Declare variables
    int emp1;
    int emp2;
    String emp1Number;
    String emp2Number;
    double hour1;
    double hour2;
    double pay1;
    double pay2;

    //Ask for employee's ID
    System.out.println("Enter ID for Employee 1: ");
    emp1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter ID for Employee 2: ");
    emp2 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Name for Employee 1: ");
    emp1Number = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter Name for Employee 2: ");
    emp2Number = input.next();a

    //Ask for employee's hours
    System.out.println("Enter Employee 1's Hours: ");
    hour1 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter Employee 2's Hours: ");
    hour2 = input.nextDouble();

    //Ask for employee's pay
    System.out.println("Enter Employee 1's Pay: ");
    pay1 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter Employee 2's Pay: ");
    pay2 = input.nextDouble();

    //Call Employee Class
    KNW_Employee e1 = new KNW_Employee(emp1,emp1Number,hour1,pay1);
    KNW_Employee e2 = new KNW_Employee(emp2,emp2Number,hour2,pay2);

    System.out.println(e1.toString());
    System.out.println(e2.toString());
  }
}
```